# How to replace all kinds of NA (true NA and character strings) in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a large data frame and there are `NA` in `integer` or `character`.
I want to replece all kinds of `NA` to `-`.
There is a smiple example as below.
The `df` like this :

```
library(tibble)
df = tibble(a = c(1,2, NA),
                b = c('a','b', 'NA'),
                c = c('1.5(1,7, 1.9)', '1.3 (1.4, 1.5)', 'NA (NA, NA)'))

> df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      a b     c             
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>         
1     1 a     1.5(1,7, 1.9) 
2     2 b     1.3 (1.4, 1.5)
3    NA NA    NA (NA, NA)
```

What I expected `df` should like this :

```
df_expected = tibble(a = c(1,2, '-'),
                     b = c('a','b', '-'),
                     c = c('1.5(1,7, 1.9)', '1.3 (1.4, 1.5)', '-'))
> df_expected
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a     b     c             
  <chr> <chr> <chr>         
1 1     a     1.5(1,7, 1.9) 
2 2     b     1.3 (1.4, 1.5)
3 -     -     -
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: "all kinds of NA" - how many types do you have? Better go with gsub with fixed match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be using `ifelse` and `grepl` inside a custom function and then call `mutate_all`.

```r
na_replace <- function(x) {
  
  ifelse(is.na(x) | grepl('NA', x), '-', x)
  
}

df %>% 
  mutate_all(na_replace)
```

Since `mutate_all` is superseded and may not receive further updates, you can use `mutate` alongside with `across`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), na_replace))
```

Both options give:

```r
## A tibble: 3 × 3
#  a     b     c             
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>         
#1 1     a     1.5(1,7, 1.9) 
#2 2     b     1.3 (1.4, 1.5)
#3 -     -     -
```

#### Edit

In case we have `BANANA`, we can scape using `'\\b'` inside `grepl`:

```r
na_replace <- function(x) {
  
  ifelse(is.na(x) | grepl('\\bNA', x, perl = TRUE), '-', x)
}

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), na_replace))
## A tibble: 3 × 3
#  a     b      c             
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>         
#1 1     a      1.5(1,7, 1.9) 
#2 2     b      1.3 (1.4, 1.5)
#3 -     BANANA -
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `mutate_all` anymore since it's superseded by the usage of `across` together with `mutate`.

Comment: `mutate_all` is [superseded](https://lifecycle.r-lib.org/articles/stages.html#superseded) which means that it will not go away.

Comment: Yes, but it won‘t benefit from any new features, so I guess it‘s preferable to the new, from the developer suggested, versions.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character),
         across(everything(), ~if_else(is.na(.) | str_detect(., "NA"), "-", .)))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  a     b     c             
  <chr> <chr> <chr>         
1 1     a     1.5(1,7, 1.9) 
2 2     b     1.3 (1.4, 1.5)
3 -     -     -
```

Comment: Just to note: "BANANA" will turn to "-", too.

Comment: True. So I should probably make sure the NA part is not preceded or followed by a letter I‘d say.